# $ variable name in Python to get os.getenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-os

My curl.trill works:

```
$ = os.getenv('$')

cookies = {
    'AlteonP': f"AKgyK+bV+AqyP5hdVrxVFA{$}",
    'JSESSIONID': '919BAF7B84FEF902E41306B1C27345E8.lgd',
}
```

But python throws this error:

```
  $ = os.getenv('$')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  $ = os.getenv('$')
    ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried changing `$` to something else but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: $ is not a sensible identifier in either Python or the shell. What makes you think it is? What error do you have when using another identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$` as the name of a variable, try this code:

```py
import os
  
key = 'HOME'
value = os.getenv(key)
print("Value of 'HOME' environment variable :", value) 
  

key = '$'
value = os.getenv(key)
print("Value of '$' environment variable :", value)
```